# why does running a php script from CRON causes character encoding issues?

Tags: php, oracle, bash, utf-8, cron

I have a php script that I run from the terminal here is what it does:

- grabs a row of data out of the database (table stores JSON strings to be processed specifically by this script);
- converts the JSON string into an array and prepares the data to be inserted into the database.
- Inserts the required data into the database

here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?PHP
    //script used to parse tweets we have gathered from the twitter streaming API
    mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

    require './config/config.php';
    require './libs/db.class.php';

    require './libs/tweetReadWrite.class.php';
    require './libs/tweetHandle.class.php';
    require './libs/tweetPrepare.class.php';
    require './libs/pushOver.class.php';
    require './libs/getLocationDetails.class.php';

    //instatiate our classes
    $twitdb = new db(Config::getConfig("twitterDbConnStr"),Config::getConfig("twitterDbUser"),Config::getConfig("twitterDbPass"));

    $pushOvr = new PushOver();                                          // push error messages to my phone
    $tweetPR = new TweetPrepare();                                      // prepares tweet data
    $geoData = new getLocationDetails($pushOvr);                        // reverse geolocation using google maps API
    $tweetIO = new TweetReadWrite($twitdb,$tweetPR,$pushOvr,$geoData);  // read and write tweet data to the database

    /* grab cached json row from the ORCALE Database
    *
    * the reason the JSON string is brought back in multiple parts is because
    * PDO doesnt handle CLOB's very well and most of the time the JSON string
    * is larger than 4000 chars - its a hack but it works
    *
    * the following sql specifies a test row to work with which has characters like €$£ etc..
    */
    $sql = "
            SELECT a.tjc_id
                 , dbms_lob.substr(tweet_json, 4000,1) part1
                 , dbms_lob.substr(tweet_json, 8000,4001) part2
                 , dbms_lob.substr(tweet_json, 12000,8001) part3
            FROM twtr_json_cache a
            WHERE a.tjc_id = 8368
            ";

    $sth = $twitdb->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();
    $data = $sth->fetchAll();

    //join JSON string back together
    $jsonRaw = $data[0]['PART1'].$data[0]['PART2'].$data[0]['PART3'];

    //shouldnt needs to do this, doesnt affect the outcome anyway
    $jsonRaw = mb_convert_encoding($jsonRaw, "UTF-8"); 

    //convert JSON object to an array
    $data = json_decode($jsonRaw,true);

    //prepares the data (grabs the data I need from the JSON object and does some
    //validation etc then finally submits to the database
    $result = $tweetIO->saveTweet($data); // returns BOOL
    echo $result;
?>
```

now if I run this from the terminal with `./proc_json_cache.php` or `php proc_json_chache.php` it works fine the data arrives in the database UTF-8 encoded and all is well, the data in the database looks like this `£$@€ < test`.

if I call this script via CRON it still saves the data but special characters like €£ etc are just squares and the data in the database looks like this `��$@��� < test`.

so far things I have tried are adding the following lines to my crontab:

```
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

this was so it matched my current shell ENV session settings and also adding the following to the bash script that calls my php script:

```
export NLS_LANG="ENGLISH_UNITED KINGDOM.AL32UTF8"
export LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
```

again to match my current shell ENV settings, but I still get the character encoding issue when the script is run from cron vs direct in the terminal.

Has anyone else had similar issues that could shed any light on how to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

here is some more information about the server:

OS: `SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11` 
PHP: `5.2.14`

Comment: Try typing `env` on your console and check if some other `env` values should be exported in your script.

Comment: what other values should I be looking for?

Comment: Instead of UTF-8, can you try ISO-8859-1 and tell if it works.

Comment: it needs to be UTF-8 as that is what the oracle database is set up to use, also the twitter API does it all in UTF-8 plus overall its more universal to keep everything UTF-8.

Comment: You could try adding *everything* from your interactive shell environment to your script, and if that works, start deleting variables that aren't needed.

Comment: That's something worth trying but there is alot of stuff in the Shell environment. Will try this tomorrow.

Comment: ok that didn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a good few hours investigating the issue, it appears that it was related to shell session variables not being passed through to the PHP script.

One thing I forgot to mention was that the script isn't being called by a cron job directly but by another daemon type PHP script which checks to see if the script was already running and if not it would use `pcntl_exec()` to call the script.

Now because I didn't pass on the environment settings as the third parameter it meant that whatever shell environment settings I was setting in the crontab where not getting passed on to my script (that shared the current process space).

So what I was actually doing was this:

```
pcntl_exec($script, $args); //script take over the process space
                            //but no continued shell env settings
```

When what I should have been doing was:

```
$a = get_defined_vars();
pcntl_exec($script, $args, $a['_SERVER']); //script take over the process space
                                           //but with shell env settings continued
```

see the php.net manual for [pcntl_exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-exec.php) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding to the bash script that calls your php script:

```
unset LANG LANGUAGE LC_CTYPE
export LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=en LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8
```

See: [Re: Crontab's charset not in utf-8](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/Ubuntu/2007-10/msg01117.html)

Comment: I did see that link before which is why i exported the LANG in the bash script, but I tried what you suggested, it didn't work :(

Comment: The `unset` is superfluous.